# People don't think about questions and answers

Tags: discussion, answer-quality, specific-question

I have question [Android application to learn English for small kids](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/26/android-application-to-learn-english-for-small-kids)

First answer recommends two wrong applications, not usable for small kids without reading and writing skills, but people are voting up for this. Probably because Duolingo is very good app.

This makes this site useless...

Comment: I agree that this answer is bad, but what is the point of your meta question? Alerting us that [we're still doing it all wrong](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/86/youre-doing-it-all-wrong)? Do you have a point about this specific question?

Comment: Yes, this is something like alert for community.  Is something than I can do myself to make this question and received answers better?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

People upvoting it just means they think the application is good, it doesn't make the site useless.

The answer that actually helps you will have a checkmark that only *you* can give out - this answer will sit at the top of the list of answers and will represent the answer that helped you.

Comment: Ok, but what with bounty? The worst and most voted answer will get my bounty?

Comment: @MariuszS Pretty much.

Comment: @MariuszS unless you manually assign it to an answer, yes

Comment: @MariuszS You can answer your own question to say that there is no software covering your requirement, and accept it. I don't know if you can assign a bou t'y to your own question, but the most important IMO is the accepted question.

Comment: This won't prevent the bounty going to the other post though - you can't assigned your own bounty to yourself.